# Conditions on substitutent function which is being substituted in definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

When we do substitution in definite integral evaluation do we need to make sure that the function from the integrand **which is being substituted for** must be bijective in the given limit of def integral or just one-one (injective) behaviour is all whats needed in the substituing function  ?

> Like for example in the substiution in case of integral from $\int_{0}^{2} \frac{lnx}{√(2x-x^2)}$ we cannot let $2x-x^2$ [substituing function ] to be new variable z because in the given limits it not bijective but one can break in into two regions of 0 to 1 and 1 to 2 in these regions the bijectivity behaviour is showned by $(2x-x^2)$ and then we can use it in that regions and evaluate separately .

Comment: Sounds right. The substituting function $x\mapsto 2x-x^2$ maps $0$ and $2$ to the same value $0$. In the new variable the integral would then run from $0$ to $0$ which is absurd.

Comment: Nice so we need bijective function or injective is sufficient ?

Comment: Hint: As we know: bijective is injective plus surjective. Can you think of a situation where you need surjective ?